# How to join 2 tables based on LIKE condition MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'HTML'),
(2, 'CSS'),
(3, 'Javascript'),
(4, 'Jquery'),
(5, 'PHP'),
;

CREATE TABLE `object` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `object` (`id`, `name`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 'Object1', 'HTML, CSS'),
(2, 'Object2', 'PHP, Javascript, HTML')
(3, 'Object3', 'PHP, Javascript');
```

Now i want to select all elements in object Table has category contain 'HTML', so what i should do?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Why you want to join two tables? as you need values from only one table and there is no relation between those 2 tables.

Comment: First of all, you have to normalize the table as you are using category name instead of category id. In case of you are using category name then join is not required at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i wanna wanna get not only specific but also generality case, the return result include data from two tables and i tried join with condition: category.name LIKE  CONCAT('%', object.category,'%') but the result is not true in few case

Answer (score 0):

Try below : Use like operator and from your question it seems to me that you don't require any join

```
select * from object
where category like '%HTML%'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I wanna get not only specific but also generality case

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: My expected output is each category display all object has category field contain that name

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to join a table using any operator in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM `category` c
INNER JOIN `object` o ON  o.category LIKE CONCAT('%', c.name, '%')
WHERE c.`name` = 'HTML'
```

although, I'd advise you to normalize your data and create one more `category_object` table for the many-to-many relation like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `category_object` (
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `objectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (categoryId)
      REFERENCES product(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (objectId)
      REFERENCES object(id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying!
I tried join with condition: category.name LIKE CONCAT('%', object.category,'%') but the result just be only right when object.category have one value